# How to add multiple values to a number depending on multiple conditions?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, countif

I have the following sheet:

[image: spreadsheet example]

and what I want to do is the following flow:

if C2 = N, add 50 to B2
if D2 = N, add 50 to B2
if E2 = N, add 50 to B2
if F2 = N, add 50 to B2

So for example, for row 2, the result in I2 would be

900 + 50 (D2=N) + 50 (E2=N) + 50 (F2=N) = 1050

How can I accomplish this via a formula?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try:

```
=B2+COUNTIF(C2:F2,"N")*50
```

Answer (score 2):

This would have to go in I2

```
=B2+IF(C2="N",50,0) +IF(D2="N",50,0)+IF(E2="N",50,0)+IF(F2="N",50,0)
```

Comment: I'd have to go with @pnuts answer. Mine's kinda the old style.

Comment: ....but it works, Mitch, that's the number one consideration - good answer!